# Is there value in maintaining the Swing [Jxxx] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Sample Swing question:

*[How to show a virtual keyboard for InputDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497258/how-to-show-a-virtual-keyboard-for-inputdialog)*

This question has the JOptionPane tag. A few questions below this (under [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)) there is a question that has the JLayeredPane tag. The right below that (if I remember correctly) there is one with the JButton tag. Questions with these tags almost universally (in my experience) include the Swing tag.

Are these tags useful? Should they be burninated? I don't think they are necessary, but I also think it's very possible that I don't fully understand the "Stack Overflow" way of doing things :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my undergraduate, I used `JOptionPane` for dinky little applications that had absolutely positively 100% certainty ***no*** bearing whatsoever to Swing.

So yes, someone can ask a question about `JOptionPane` and not about Swing.
No, we should not burninate this tag or tags similar to it.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and it goes right to the crux of my question: Understanding your situation, if someone was to post a question about JOptionPane but not include Swing, users like me who are watching [Swing] but not [JOptionPane] wmight not see the question, even though we might be able to help. If we burninate and just have Swing, the question might be more visible. You like it the way it is though?

Comment: How do I know you're not going to swoop in with a Swing-based solution @ControlAltDel?  As in, would I be assured that asking a question that's only just about getting this value from a `JOptionPane` be what would be answered without me suddenly needing to learn about this other thing that is apparently related to the thing I'm using but was never told about?

Comment: To your question of "how do I know you're not..." The philosophy (as I understand it on SO) is to try to create questions with answers that can be useful for others too. In my own programming when I have questions, I often find questions where the "correct" answer is not the answer I am looking for - that there is a better answer that fits with what I am looking for. What you are seeking (limiting solutions to the learning level of the person asking the question) seems antithetical to this philosophy. And you can always specify in the question or in comments the kind of solution you desire.

Comment: In principle I agree with your motivation @ControlAltDel, but today I'm roleplaying as the archetypical Stack Overflow question asker.  I don't really care about any of this other fancy stuff, I just want you to answer *my* question, and I'm not asking about this Swing thing or whatever.  I just want to ask about my issues with why this stupid JOptionPane thing isn't working, and I can't get a hold of classmates or my instructor.